# Connecting to MongoDB database

Tags: javascript, mongodb, connection

I am trying to connect to a MongoDB database.I have followed all the steps here https://youtu.be/EcJERV3IiLM but am getting an error.

The index.js file looks like this,

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
dotenv.config()
const mongodb = require('mongodb')

mongodb.connect(process.env.CONNECTIONSTRING, async function(err,client){
  const db = client.db()
  const results = await  db.collection("student").find().toArray()
  console.log(results)
```

The error I get is,

```
mongodb.connect is not a function
```

So it seems to be reading as far line 5:9 which is mongodb.connect in index.js and just stops.

I  put this file index.js beside the .env file and beside that .gitignore which contains the the .env file. The .env file has the code which I copied from the Mongodb AtlSAS Cloud Service.

I also created a user and and autogenerated and saved a password. Both of which I placed in the string. And I put in the string the name of the database name "blah" The table/document is called "student". That's in the index.js code above. So the database name and the document name are blah.student.

I documented what I tried here, http://www.shanegibney.com/shanegibney/mongodb-setup/

The tutorial video is here, https://youtu.be/EcJERV3IiLM

I am on Ubuntu Linux.

I am currently running index.js in the terminal in a directory called mongostack, with

```
node index.js
```

but should I use,

```
nodemon index.js
```

And for this should I install nodemon and how do I do that?

Do I need to download it first and if so where do I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to get MongoClient. Try changing:

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb')
```

to:

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
```

Comment: you have to instantiate `MongoClient`

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a MongoClient see https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/quick-start/

```js
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");

const uri = process.env.CONNECTIONSTRING;
const client = new MongoClient(uri);
async function run() {
  await client.connect();
  const db = client.db("yourdb")
  const results = await db.collection("student").find().toArray()
  console.log(results)
}
run();
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I copied your code const dotenv = require('dotenv')
dotenv.config()
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb')

const uri = process.env.CONNECTIONSTRING;
const client = new MongoClient(uri);
async function run() {
  const db = client.db("blah")
  const results = await db.collection("student").find().toArray()
  console.log(results)
}
run(); into index.js

Comment: This gives (node:160505) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNotConnectedError: MongoClient must be connected to perform this operation
    at getTopology (/home/shane/mongostack/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:282:11)
    at Collection.find 
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
(node:160505) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the

Comment: .... To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:160505) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: @ShaneG please see the updated answer

Comment: The comment doesn't have enough to leave the answer here. So the aswer is at http://www.shanegibney.com/shanegibney/error/